# Is it possible for the filter from the quarkus extension to set priority?

Tags: java, quarkus

Is it possible in any way to set the execution priority to a filter from an extension implementing `ContainerResponseFilter`?

**Details:**

As I looked, with the usual behavior, the filters of the main application are executed first, and then filters from extensions.
However, in my case, it is necessary that the filter from the extension is executed before the filters of the main application. Or at least up to the filters from the other extensions of the main application.

**Example:**

`ContainerResponseFilter[] responseFilters` from the `ContainerResponseContextImpl`.

What I have:

`responseFilters = [app filter][app filter][extension filter][extension filter][MY EXTENSION FILTER][extension filter]`

I want to have:

`responseFilters = [MY EXTENSION FILTER][app filter][app filter][extension filter][extension filter][extension filter]`

OR

`responseFilters = [app filter][app filter][MY EXTENSION FILTER][extension filter][extension filter][extension filter]`

**Question:** So, is it possible to do this?

**What have I tried:**

1. I tried to assign my filter `@Priority(1)`. Then my filter flew to the end of the `responseFilters` array and was executed last.
2. I tried to create a dummy filter in the main application that implements `ContainerResponseFilter` and has `@Priority(2)`. And I assigned `@Priority(1)` to my filter from the extension. Then filters flew to the end of the `responseFilters` array, and the dummy filter with priority 2 was executed earlier than the filter from the extension with priority 1.

Comment: How are you registering the extension response filter?

Comment: Hello, Like this:
```@Provider
public class MyExtensionResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one very non-obvious detail:
[image: Filters priority]

I tried to assign my filter `@Priority(1)` but in fact I needed to set a large value because the priority of filters in the response is calculated in reverse order.

Since all response filters from the main application have the default priority `@Priority(Priorities.USER)`, I had to set a higher value.

My final code looks like this:

```java
@Priority(Priorities.USER + 1)
@Provider
public class MyExtensionResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
```